# 1C: Предприятие 8.3 Как выдать наименование из разных справочников

Tags: 1с

У нас есть много справочников и у каждого из них есть наименование. Можно ли как-то в справочнике "Закупка" указать так, чтобы реквизит "Наименование" выпадающим списком "Справочники.Ссылка" выбиралось из всех справочников, а не с конкретного одного.[image: скриншот]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос не связан с [тематикой сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

В общем я такой человек, что мне нужна помощь, я спрашиваю или задаю вопрос и буквально через некоторое небольшое время я сам же на него и отвечаю, в общем я в реквизите "НаименованиеПредмета" поставил тип значения "Справочник.Ссылка", далее в самом справочнике "Закупка" я указал в поле "Вводится на основании" все нужные мне справочники, и уже в полях заполнения я просто выбираю справочник и там следом открывается окно что входит в этот справочник и тупо выбираю что надо, всё.

Comment: осталось понять каким образом Ваш вопрос подходит под [тематику сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся:
к проектированию, использованию и администрированию баз данных

Comment: @Alex + "к реальной проблеме, встречающейся на практике, решение которой можно изложить кратко в паре абзацев, и которая уникальна для разработки программного обеспечения и профессионального администрирования IT систем." -- что не так с вопросом?

Answer (score 1):

Вам стоит рассмотреть реорганизацию метаданных. Например, в типовых конфигурациях есть единый справочник Номенклатура, с реквизитом Справочник.ВидыНоменклатуры. Так же и вам стоит вместо создания отдельного справочника под каждую категорию товаров стоит завести один.